# Comparing treatment effects across groups

Tags: experiment-design, treatment-effect, observational-study, case-control-study, treatment

I created two donation campaigns, one loss framed (N:1993) and one gained framed (N:1989)  I understood donations are usually veeeery low and the sample was a lot smaller than previously expected, so I had to let go the idea of having a control group (as if I divided my group into three I most likely would have gotten null results for all, plus, how does a control donation campaign look like?). I conducted stratified randomization, making sure both gain and loss treatment were balanced across relevant covariates. Now, as I analyse my data, I can find that there are significant differences in favour of the loss treatment, both in probability of donation and donation amount. I can conduct both an Intention to treat analysis and also a compliers only analysis (as I have data of who opened the emails). Results hold for for both types of analysis.  My main concern now h is, I don't have a control group,  so am I limited to just compare both treatments in both donation amount and donation probability? (and check for maybe heterogeneous effects)
Now, I might be able to access data of previous donation campaigns (not designed by me, and most likely sent to the whole sample), would that be beneficial to my analysis? For example, there is a "valentines" campaign that was carried out one month before mine... could that be a potentially valid control?

Comment: You could try to do something like this and use regression and/or matching to try to adjust but it sounds like your results would be rather speculative, so maybe not worth doing.

Comment: What is control in this case? If someone was in a campaign, aren't they in a treatment?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I thought. Now ofcourse, the treatmeant is the framing of the campaign.. Loss frame vs gain frame, given that loss aversion would dictate that people might donate more when faced with the loss framed campaign. I just didnt see a control here